# Why iPhone SE stays with a black display always after screen lock

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

A few days ago, my iPhone stuck in a black screen. It was ON, I could use Siri, and every call or message were entering ok. Also, when toogling the silence switch, the iPhone vibrated.

I realized that it happens every time the display goes to a sleep mode (with power button, locked iPhone). Even though I use assistive touch to lock it, it happens the same. I wait so the auto lock triggers the locking, it happens the same.

In addition, recently I discovered some issues with the camera app. When trying to take a photo, it just show a blurred static image from the context. When switching to video capture, it gets fixed and now I see what I intend to capture. Now when I go back to photo capture mode, it shows well but I can't switch among cameras (front, back side). In video capture mode I can switch among cameras perfectly.

I already made (like three times) a full restore, using iTunes with the most updated software (iOS 10.0.2). I also chatted with apple support. I'm able to see the log files in my mac, and I see several kind of errors (I don't know if they are common or unusual).

My guess is ambiguous: 
  - It may be hardware issue with the flex of the display or some kind of connector inside. But in that case I think the iPhone would go black randomly, and not only after locking it.
  - It may be software issue: I didn't find another person with an iPhone SE suffering my same problem. After a full restore, and updating to the latest software, any kind of software problems shoud have been fixed at this time.

Update: I experienced very wierd actions. See at these screenshots:
[image: bad text position in touch id config]
[image: flash is disabled]

Comment: Did you restore from backup or set up as new? I'm wondering if anything in the backup might just be put back & still 'break' it.

Comment: I tried both. First, I restored from backup. The error appeared again. Then I tried restoring and configuring as a new iPhone. The error once again showed up. One more time I restored but this time with a backup from another iPhone. The error is driving me crazy, again. It's frustrating.

Comment: I have the same problem. The screen on my SE doesn't wake up after sleep. Pushing the start button for 5 seconds or so restarts *part* of the OS: I get the B/W startup screen with the Apple logo and have to enter the PIN that unlocks the screen (TouchID is disabled in this state) but I don't need to enter the PIN to the SIM after that, something you otherwise have to do after a proper restart. Somehow it seems it is the Window Manager or similar process that hangs, which makes sense since it is when the screen saver kicks in this happens.

Comment: @d-b I had to go to apple and they told me that my iPhone had an issue in its motherboard. So they gave me a new one. (It was frustrating)